# UISearchBar stays active when changing view via TabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uitabbar, dismiss

I'm working on an iOS application using **Objective C**. My ViewController contains a **UITableViewController** on which I have set a **SearchBar** with Scope buttons. To navigate through the application, I use a **tabBar** locate at the bottom of the screen.

Everything is working well except a "*little detail*". Here is the scenario causing the bad behaviour :

```
1) Touching the tab bar to "select" it. The keyboard and the scope bar appear.
2) Changing tabs using the TabBar
3) Coming back to the ViewController with the SearchBar
```

When I reach step 3, the view displayed is completely black except the **SearchBar** which is still **enable**.

I tried to add a lot of different solutions in `viewWillDisappear` to **dismiss the SearchBar** before leaving my first tab but nothing worked for now.

Here are the solutions I tried in `viewWillDisappear` :

- `[self searchBarCancelButtonClicked:self.searchController.searchBar];`
- `self.searchDisplayController.active = NO;`
- `[self.searchController.searchBar resignFirstResponder];`

If you have any idea of how to deal with that problem, let me know !
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Before changing the tab you need to call this:

self.searchController.active = NO;

Answer (score 0):

With Swift 4 this does the trick:

```
searchController.isActive = false
```